# Why does my program not work when I use the "randomSelect" method to replace several lines of code

Tags: c++, methods, grid

> The scatter method takes the original image and scatter its pixels.
>   The program works well when I use several lines of code instead of the
>   method "randomSelect". The program seems to go into an infinite loop
>   and the image does not change when I use the method "randomSelect".

```
void scatter(GBufferedImage &img, Grid<int> original, int row, int col) {
    int degree;
    while (true) {
        degree = getInteger("Enter degree of scatter [1-100]: ");
        if (degree >=1 && degree <= 100) break;
    }

    Grid<int> newImg(row, col);


    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

      /*    int newRow = -1;
            int newCol = -1;
            while (!original.inBounds(newRow, newCol)) {
                newRow = randomInteger(max(i - degree, 0), min(i + degree,original.numRows()));
                newCol = randomInteger(max(j - degree, 0), min(j + degree,original.numRows()));
            }
            newImg[i][j] = original[newRow][newCol];   */    // work properly

        newImg[i][j] = randomSelect(original, i , j, degree);  // do not work

        }
    }

    img.fromGrid(newImg);
}



int randomSelect(Grid<int> original, int i, int j, int degree) {     // do not work
    int newRow = -1;
    int newCol = -1;
    while (!original.inBounds(newRow, newCol)) {
        newRow = randomInteger(max(i - degree, 0), min(i + degree,original.numRows()));
        newCol = randomInteger(max(j - degree, 0), min(j + degree,original.numRows()));
    }

    return original[newRow][newCol];
}
```

Comment: You probably want to pass `Grid<int> original` by reference: `Grid<int>& original`.

Comment: It works. But why cannot I pass a copy of original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass original as a reference:

```
int randomSelect(Grid<int>& original, int i, int j, int degree) {     // will work
```

Comment: @ZuweiShui I am not sure if and how the copy constructor of Grid implemented. Nevertheless, it's more efficient to pass a reference.

Comment: So, the reason of my program seems to go into an infinite loop and the image does not change when i pass the copy of original is lack of efficiency. Is that right?

Comment: Not sure, maybe. If the grid is big and there are many iterations it can be the case. But another option is that the copy constructor is not implemented correctly.